# mongoose schema ignores values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose

I'm giving up.

I have a Schema defined like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    userNick      : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true, sparse: true } }
  , userEmail     : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true, sparse: true } }
  , userPass      : { type: String, required: true }
  , userRole      : { type: String, default: 4 }
  , userFirstname : String
  , userLastname  : String
  , userImage       : String
  , userBday        : { type: Date, required: true }
  , userCreated   : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
var userModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);
```

Nothing special I thought. But userRole and userBday are ignored when I try to save the new user.
I use a input type=date for Birthday and splitting the value like this:

```
var bdayReformat = data.BDay.split('-');
var bDay = new Date(bdayReformat[0], bdayReformat[1]-1, bdayReformat[2]);
```

This returns: Thu Apr 05 1973 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CEST)

I declare:

```
account = new userModel({
    userNick      : data.Nickname
  , userEmail     : data.Email
  , userPass      : data.Password
  , userFirstname : data.Firstname
  , userLastname  : data.Lastname
  , userImage     : 'media/noimage.png'
  , userBday      : bDay
});
```

Then i'am saving:
This is the result:

```
{ userNick: 'XXXXXXX',
  userEmail: 'XXX@XXXXX.de',
  userPass: 'XXXXXXX',
  userImage: 'media/noimage.png',
  _id: 50cdb5d77fbdc88013000001,
  userCreated: Sun Dec 16 2012 12:51:51 GMT+0100 (CET) }
```

I've no idea why userRole or bDay is not saved.
I'm a beginner in serversideprogramming and an absolute beginner in mongodb and mongoose.

Thanks for helping
I'm using Nodejs v0.8.15
mongoose 3.5
storing in azurecloud with the a free mongolab-db

IDE (if you have a tip) is Webstorm 5
and i'm on a MAC

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with your code.  `bDay` and `userRole` both appear in the newly added doc.

Comment: If you are running this code you got a different result?

Comment: Right; copied your code as much as possible and it doesn't have the problem of missing fields.

Comment: I'm looking for a deep hole and change my job... it is a simple error. I've copied some codesegments from another project. What happened is that my schema was a dublication. So the other Scheme was used and there are no fields for userRole and Birthday. Thank you very much. Without your comment I never get the idea to look for double code.

Comment: Can you mark this as self answered then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answered. It was a problem with double code.